# Pandas Column Object Bucketed Value Extract

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In a Pandas dataframe, I have one column with values like this: `[2017-06-13 00:00:00, 2017-06-14 00:00:00)`. Is there a quick way to pull out the first date `2017-06-13 00:00:00`?

Thanks!

EDIT: The parentheses at the end of the string is not a typo.

Comment: Try my edit answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[0,'Column1'][0]
Out[85]: 'x'
```

Sample Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[['x','y'], ['a','b']],
                   'Out1':[1, 2]})
```

If you need pull out whole column

```
df.Column1.apply(pd.Series)[0]
Out[88]: 
0    x
1    a
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

---

***EDIT, Not a typo ...***

```
df.Column1.str.split(',',expand=True)[0].str[1:]

Out[97]: 
0    2017-06-13 00:00:00
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Data input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':['[2017-06-13 00:00:00, 2017-06-14 00:00:00)']})
```

Comment: You beat me to it. :)

Comment: @alpacafondue Yw~

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

df

```
    date
0   [2017-06-13 00:00:00, 2017-06-14 00:00:00]
```

after apply

```
date
0   2017-06-13 00:00:00
```

Timings:

```
df['date'].apply(lambda x: x[0])    
280 µs ± 17.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

df.date.apply(pd.Series)[0]
1.38 ms ± 89.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This returned `[`.  `[2017-06-13 00:00:00, 2017-06-14 00:00:00)` is weird because it has a parentheses at the end.

Comment: I assumed the parenthesis to be a typo. Doesn't your column value look like  [2017-06-13 00:00:00, 2017-06-14 00:00:00]?

Comment: That's the weird thing. The dataframe is created from a SQL query which, in this particular query language, buckets days with the parentheses at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.str` accessor with split:

```
df['DatesList'].str.split(',',expand=True)[0].str[1:].values[0]
```

Output:

```
'2017-06-13 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This returned `[`. `[2017-06-13 00:00:00, 2017-06-14 00:00:00)` is weird because it has a parentheses at the end (not a typo).

Comment: Oh... that is one long string not a true list.  Okay.